# Не могу войти использую мой глобальный (англоязычный) stackexchange account

Tags: поддержка, статус-так-задумано, аутентификация

Не могу войти использую мой глобальный (англоязычный) stackexchange account

P.S. Хотя нет, могу, а почему репутация тут 101 вместо той, которая у меня на stackoverlow?

Comment: А на японском SO ты тоже есть?))

Comment: @Qwertiy: [Нет](http://stackexchange.com/users/3349208/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AC%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9?tab=accounts).

Comment: @VladD, зато в японском языке есть. А чего же не на SO?

Comment: @Qwertiy: В этой точке заряд моего хрустального шара закончился, и я переадресую вопрос ТС'у.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что ru.SO и SO — различные сайты, вот и репутация на них разная. Вам дали 100 бонусных очков за то, что вы не новичок на другом сайте сети (а именно — на английском SO), и с этим бонусом ограничения, налагаемые на новичков, вас не будут затрагивать.

---

Ответ из комментария [@VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd).